# MySQL: How to INSERT VALUE INTO TABLE if a value in another table is NULL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have:

```
INSERT INTO ItemTracking(`Item`, `Source`, `LeftSourceAt`)
SELECT `Item`, `Source`, now() FROM ItemAvailability WHERE Item = 'PA';
```

I want to execute the above query **ONLY IF** `ItemBeingTracked` in `ItemAvailability` is `NULL`.

Edit: `If ItemAvailability.ItemBeingTracked == NULL Then` do the above query.

Comment: and how do you identify a specific record of the `table1` entity? do you have an id or something?

Comment: Yes, I have ID (something like `Item = 'PA'`)

Comment: Correct! I edited the post..

Comment: Iam trying it now..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you would just add the condition to the `WHERE`:

```
INSERT INTO ItemTracking(Item, `Source`, LeftSourceAt)
    SELECT Item, `Source`, now()
    FROM ItemAvailability
    WHERE Item = 'PA' AND ItemBeingTracked IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 1):

a bit rusty with SQL, but I believe this is one way to go about it.

```
INSERT INTO ItemTracking(`Item`, `Source`, `LeftSourceAt`)
SELECT `Item`, `Source`, now() 
FROM ItemAvailability 
WHERE Item = 'PA' AND ItemBeingTracked IS NULL;
```

Comment: Instead of inserting only `'PA'`, it put all the rows in `ItemAvailability`

Comment: then your description is ambiguous, see Gordon's answer as he posted it first but I've updated mine to accommodate your comment.